# ld.exe cannot open output file E:\CLG WRK\cpp\Reverse.exe: Permission denied, [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, arrays, array-reverse

I am working on an array problem in which I have to reverse an array.
I wrote this code but it is not working:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void rev(int reversed_array[], int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            reversed_array[i]=arr[i];
        }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={11,2,3,4,5};
    int n;
    n= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int reversed_array[n];

    rev(reversed_array,arr,n);

    cout<<reversed_array[0];
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me error like:

```
ld.exe  cannot open output file E:\CLG WRK\cpp\Reverse.exe: Permission denied 
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

**I tried:**

1. Restarted my IDE -> No difference
2. Used online compiler -> No errors but shows the wrong output(11, instead of 5)

[Here is an IDE Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVQr4.png)

Comment: Most likely your program is already running. Kill it with the task manager.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks. 
I tried this and you were right.
But its giving me wrong output(11, instead of 5)

Comment: That's because you just copy one array to the other without reversing.

Comment: Yea correct, So I changed it, and now it gives me output- [5432] instead of [543211]
Code:
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void rev(int reversed_array[], int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            reversed_array[i]=arr[n-i];
        }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={11,2,3,4,5};
    int n;
    n= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int reversed_array[n];
 n=n-1;
    rev(reversed_array,arr,n);
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<reversed_array[i];
        }
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: okay i got it, thanks. :)